# On the predual of the James tree space $\mathit{JT}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

$\newcommand\JT{\mathit{JT}}$The James tree space $\JT$ was the first example of a separable Banach space containing no copies of $\ell_1$ such that its dual space is non-separable. Since $\JT$ admits a monotone boundedly complete Schauder basis, the closed subspace generated by the coefficient functionals in the dual of $\JT$ is a predual of $\JT$, that we denote $B$.
There is an explicit expression for the norm in $\JT$, and $\JT$ is hereditarily-$\ell_2$ (each closed infinite dimensional subspace of $\JT$ contains an isomorphic copy of $\ell_2$). For these results, we refer to the book [The James forest](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511662379), by H. Fetter and B. Gamboa de Buen.

My Questions:

1. Is this predual $B$ hereditarily-$\ell_2$?
2. Is there an explicit expression for the norm in $B$?

Comment: I think that both questions have a positive answer.A natural candidate for an equivalent norm is the following. Denote by $\Delta $ the dyadic tree and by $I$ its finite intervals. For such a $I$ we set $I^ {o}$ the interval without its ends.For $x \in c_{00} (\Delta ) $ we set $\| x\| = sup\{ (\sum_{i=1} ^{n} (I_{i}^{max} - I_{i}^{min})^{2} )^{1/2}$ where $\{I_i ^{o} \}_{i=1} ^ n$ are disjoint intervals$\}$

Comment: Write $x (I_{i} ^{max}) $ instead of  $I_{i} ^{max} $  and also  $x (I_{i} ^{min}) $ instead of  $I_{i} ^{min} $ .

Comment: It is coherent with the duality between $J$ and its dual, and that the branches in $T$ generate copies of $J$ in $JT$.

Comment: Exactly, towards the branches of $\Delta $ the norms of $JT$ and its dual are the corresponding  norms of $J$ and its dual. The rest are connected in $l_2$ norm. This is the reason to call such a norm as "a natural candidate".

Comment: With this new norm, the branches would generate copies of $J$ in the predual of $JT$. So it does not give an equivalent norm in the predual.

Comment: I do not see this. However probably we need to notice that we consider intervals with at least two elements. Also the disjointness of $I_{i}^o $could be changed to something similar but it is not clear to me. I do not have a proof, it is simply a guess.

Comment: In James' original paper (Bull AMS 1974, p. 739), for example, you can find two expressions for the norm in J using the usual basis and the summing basis. These two expressions coincide with the norm in JT and the proposed norm in the predual restricted to a branch. And J does not embed in its dual.

Comment: The  system does not allow further discussion and moreover I do not have something more to say.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.